# How to create an XSLT file from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xslt, xslt-2.0

I Have a python program that looks for a particular document in server. If the document is found, it performs some operations. I also need to create an XSLT file which gives me info about whether the document is found or not.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template name="Dunning">
    <xsl:param name="Image"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Image = 'ABC'">
            <xsl:text>Found</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$Image = 'MNO'">
            <xsl:text>NotFound</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need an XSLT because i need to read this file from another XSLT.
Its easier for me to call this template "Dunning" from my main XSLT.
How do i achieve this?

If its possible for XSLT to read a comma separated file, i could create a file like this:

```
ABC,Found
MNO,NotFound
```

But im not sure how XSLT will read a comma separated file. Please let me know if its possible.

Comment: As for reading comma separated text files with XSLT, this is possible since XSLT 2 with the  `unparsed-text` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-unparsed-text. The current version of XSLT is 3.0 and is supported from Python through the use of `saxonche` https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best options to create XML is XSLT, so to create XSLT, as it is XML, you can of course use XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform-alias"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="axsl" result-prefix="xsl"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="image-names" as="xs:string*" select="'ABC', 'MNO'"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <axsl:stylesheet version="3.0">
      <axsl:template name="Dunning">
        <axsl:param name="Image"/>
        <axsl:choose>
            <axsl:when test="$Image = '{$image-names[1]}'">
                <axsl:text>Found</axsl:text>
            </axsl:when>
            <axsl:when test="$Image = '{$image-names[2]}'">
                <axsl:text>NotFound</axsl:text>
            </axsl:when>
        </axsl:choose>
     </axsl:template>
    </axsl:stylesheet>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To run the XSLT with Python 3 and saxonche, you can use code like the following (shows first running the XSLT with the default parameter values but then as well after setting the parameters from Python):

```
from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor, PyXdmValue

with PySaxonProcessor() as saxon_proc:
    xslt30_processor = saxon_proc.new_xslt30_processor()

    xslt30_executable = xslt30_processor.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_file='sample1.xsl')

    stylesheet_result = xslt30_executable.call_template_returning_value()

    print(stylesheet_result)

    xdm_seq = PyXdmValue()

    xdm_string1 = saxon_proc.make_string_value('DEF')

    xdm_seq.add_xdm_item(xdm_string1)

    xdm_string2 = saxon_proc.make_string_value('PQR')

    xdm_seq.add_xdm_item(xdm_string2)

    xslt30_executable.set_parameter('image-names', xdm_seq)

    stylesheet_result = xslt30_executable.call_template_returning_value()

    print(stylesheet_result)
```